# django no module named 'settings'

Tags: python-3.x, django

i inherited a python project where django is used.
for my devs, i needed the transaction module of django.

so i went to '**P:\file\ourLibrary\server\config\settings.py**' and updated the

```
**DATABASES = {
    'default': { filled infos }**
```

then in Powershell i set the ENV_VARIABLE  **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE** to the *path specified before*

i then tried to use the ***function that uses the @transaction.atomic***
but i had the folowing error

```
> You must either define the **environment variable
> DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE** or call **settings.configure()** before
> accessing settings.
```

which i don't understand because i already setted it.

i found various posts in StackOverflow that suggest to use

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','P:\file\ourLibrary\server\config\settings')
```

but now when i use the @transaction function
i got

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named **'P:\file\ourLibrary\server\config\settings'**
```

what am i doing wrong here?

thank you for your help,

Comment: `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')`

Comment: The path needs to be set in terms of the Python import path. Try `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ourLibrary.server.config.settings')`

Comment: thanks it worked @BhavyaPeshavaria but why do i need to pass by this setdefault?

Comment: This is where the apps will look for configurations defined in settings. We do not need to set it manually when we run the Django server because manage.py sets this for us; in fact, it is the first line in the function, check out the code of it. Converting the above comment to an answer so that it is searchable.

Answer (score 1):

The path needs to be set in terms of the Python import path. Try

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ourLibrary.server.config.settings')
```